# Is tidal energy an infinite source of energy?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, energy-conservation, dissipation, tidal-effect

As tidal waves are caused due to gravitational force which acts infinitely until the presence of mass (the Moon) which make me think of an infinite source of energy. So what's wrong in here?

Answer (score 2):

The Earth is slowing down because of tides due to the friction of water as it moves around, so it is not an 'infinite' source of energy.

https://www.jpl.nasa.gov/news/earths-rotation-slows-down

Once the Earth slows down enough, the Moon will be tidally locked : 1 rotation of Earth for 1 orbit of the Moon. So there will be no more tides, as the Moon will always be in the same position.

But this is a very slow process, the sun will have died (and vaporized the Earth and the Moon in the process) before this happens:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tidal_acceleration